# JavaScript fadein with checkbox popup not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm making a popup checkbox but when i try to display it, it's not showing anything even though a regular alert is working.. i've used fadein many times when making login popups idk why it's not working here.

```
<form>
        <div class="Style-popup">
            <div class="InnerStyle-popup">
                    <label class="container">One
                      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
                      <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>

                    <label class="container">Two
                      <input type="checkbox">
                      <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>

                    <label class="container">Three
                      <input type="checkbox">
                      <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>

                    <label class="container">Four
                      <input type="checkbox">
                      <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
              </div>
            </div>

    </form>

$('.define-style').click(function(){

    $('.Style-popup').fadeIn();
    //alert('dss');
```

});

Comment: I don't see any elements with the class "define-style". Are those in a different part of the code?

Comment: Hey @Heather, try providing the code at https://codepen.io/pen/ and I bet someone can help you

Comment: How are you initially hiding the Style-popup? what is the visibility/display for InnerStyle-popup?

Comment: hey, "define-style" is the button class i'm using a display:none in the css styling for the form @showdev

Comment: i'm using a display:none in the css styling for the form @NawedKhan

Comment: @Heather so the form is still hidden and you are making the div with class Style-popup to fade in. Don't hide the form, hide the div with class .Style-popup

Comment: @NawedKhan it's working now, thank youuu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Code goes here

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.define-style').click(function(){ 
    $('form').fadeIn();    
});
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

form{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@3.2.1" data-semver="3.2.1" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form>
      <div class="Style-popup">
        <div class="InnerStyle-popup">
          <label class="container">One
                                  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
          <label class="container">Two
                                  <input type="checkbox" />
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
          <label class="container">Three
                                  <input type="checkbox" />
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
          <label class="container">Four
                                  <input type="checkbox" />
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <button class="define-style">Fade</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

if you are setting display none to form, try fadeIn the form as :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.define-style').click(function(){ 
    $('form').fadeIn();    
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

have to see more of your code. i filled in the blanks and fadeIn works for me

```
<body>
  <form class="define-style">
    <div class="Style-popup">
      <div class="InnerStyle-popup">
        <label class="container">One
          <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>

        <label class="container">Two
          <input type="checkbox">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>

        <label class="container">Three
          <input type="checkbox">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>

        <label class="container">Four
          <input type="checkbox">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>
```

CSS

```
.define-style {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.Style-popup {
  display: none;
}
```

jQuery

```
'use strict';

$('.define-style').click(function(){

  $('.Style-popup').fadeIn(2000);
  // alert('dss');
});
```

Comment: define-style is the button class @Vinh Nguyen

Comment: well looking at more of your comments, I see you're setting the form display to none, but then trying to fadeIn the inputs in the form, which would not make it appear. you need to target the form for the fadeIn. The other answer should do it, except it has double closing brackets and parenthesis at the end @Heather

Comment: $('.define-style').click(function(){

  $('form').fadeIn();
  // alert('dss');
});     //works on my end but I would need to see your exact code to see why it wouldnt work for you